# Eclipse cannot find JVM.dll

Tags: java, eclipse

When I attempt to install eclipse, I recieve an error stating that "Eclipse cannot find `jvm.dll`, as it is not located in my `/bin` folder. I cannot seem to locate this file on my machine nor is it located in the `/bin` folder. Would I have to download this file and place it in my `/bin` folder?

Comment: I have edited my question to make it more clear as to what I am asking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using eclipse 64 bit version and your jdk is 32 bit. Try installing 64 bit jdk or using 32 bit eclipse

Comment: It can also be the other way. Your eclipse is 32 bit and your jdk is 64 bit

Comment: @ihebiheb sure.You need to check both eclipse and JDK versions are the same.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not have this located on my machine

It depends on what you mean by that.

If you mean that you don't know where to look to find it, then try windows search.

If you mean that you have looked, but the file is not present anywhere, then ... yes ... your installation didn't work.

If you mean that you have found the DLL, but it is not in "/bin" where you expect it to be, then you need to configure Eclipse to look for it in the place where you found it.

Comment: I have tried a windows search and cannot find this file. Would a solution to this problem be to download the file off of the internet. I recieved a message when installing JDK V7.0 that said I had a more recent version of Java on my machine. The other version of java does not contain the jvm.dll file either.

Comment: Downloading jvm.dll from the net is definitely the wrong answer, but I'm not sure what the right answer is.  (I'm a Linux person)  Maybe someone else can answer this for you.